# Orbeon Forms: Split Text into Control Fields

Tags: orbeon

We are pasting the following text into a **Plain Text Area** control:

{
"FIELD1":VALUE1,
"FIELD2":VALUE2,
"FIELD3":VALUE3,
"FIELD4":VALUE4
}

Then we need to unpack this data into separate fields within the form.

How can we achieve this?

Many thanks in advance.

PeteA

Comment: We found the answer using a Calculated Value within the controls using:


translate(substring-before(substring-after($vc_test, 'FIELD1":'), ','), '"', '') or
translate(substring-before(substring-after($vc_test, 'FIELD2":'), ','), '"', '')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user-entered value is in JSON format, you can also use the `xxf:json-to-xml()` function, which makes this both easier and more robust.

[image: See the function in action]

For reference:

- The two fields to the right of the text area use the expressions `xxf:json-to-xml($json)/json/author` and `xxf:json-to-xml($json)/json/date`.
- The source for this form is available [here](https://gist.github.com/avernet/28173b36789a236bc7b0ab0e402a6f7a).

Comment: Many thanks Alex

Answer (score 0):

See last explanation above using a Calculated Value formula.